# Extension of native prototypes, good or bad practice?

Tags: javascript, prototyping

Today I stumbled upon [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) page on the Mozilla Developer Network.
In it, not only it is stated that it's a bad practice to extend native prototypes, but also that there is only one exception to this, and that is when one wants to backport features of newer javascript engines.

The justification given is:

> This technique is called monkey patching and breaks encapsulation. While used by popular frameworks such as Prototype.js, there is still no good reason for cluttering built-in types with additional non-standard functionality.

Still, I fail to grasp why is this a bad practice. Additionally, if for example we want to add some functionality to Array objects how should we do it?

Comment: This question already has answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/1679537).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it already has an answer at Stack Overflow here: **[Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/439793)** However, it cannot be marked as a duplicate because the question was answered on a different Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @Snowman - Seems more off topic in stackoverflow

Comment: @Gnomo: Asking "What is best practice" is sketchy, because we typically don't know how to judge that, since the OP seldom provides his specific requirements.  Asking "why is something considered a best practice" is often educational, because it picks apart the belief.  Such questions typically fare well both here and on Stack Overflow.  Stack Overflow isn't just a troubleshooting tool, despite much effort by many people to turn it into one.

Comment: To be clear, I do not believe this is necessarily a bad question regardless of site or which side of the off-topic line it is. I feel that any answers it would attract would be substantially equivalent to the answers on that other question.

Comment: Just found that there is a question [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/104320) on programmers with a more comprehensive answer.